# Relationship while controlling for variables

Tags: regression, econometrics

what does it mean when a question states controlling for other variables. for example I came across this question,

Estimate a quadratic relationship between lnhourpay and age, controlling for gender (sex), and years of schooling (edage).

does it mean to regress with variables lnhourpay age agesqr sex edage,

or

does it mean to regress with interactive variables lnhourpay age agesqr sex edage agesqr_sex agesqr_edage edage_sex.

I am confused what it means when questions states controlling for other variables?

I am doing basic econometric so please avoid advanced level explanations.

Comment: Excellent question that could cause much headaches for a lot of researchers. Usually it is done without interactions. But this doesnt mean it is always smart. You could also ask for further non-linear terms of edage...